# How to disable a Perl button until external command is executed?

Tags: windows, perl, batch-file, perltk

```
sub push_button2
{
    $but2->configure(-state => 'disabled');

    open(launch, "+>C:\\integration\\check_label\\launch_check_label.bat") or die "Couldn't open file launch_check_label.bat$!";
    print launch "$ARGV[1]:\n";
    print launch "perl C:\\integration\\check_label\\check_label.pl $ARGV[0] $ARGV[1] $text";

    system("start C:\\integration\\check_label\\external_command.bat");
    $but2->configure(-state => 'normal');
}
```

Above code snippet didn't work out, it only disabled the button for some milliseconds and the button was active in no time even before the batch file ran.

Comment: Is it possible that the `start` command opens it as a background process instead of a blocking process? That would explain why it's so fast.

Comment: Yes ,its kind of a parallel process.I have to wait until that background/parallel process is executed .

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close `launch` before executing your `system` command.

If output to the `launch` file handle is buffered (typically to 4KB), then your file is probably empty at the time the `system` command is run.  If your `system` command would return right away in that case, then your button would reactivate immediately too.

Just before your `system` command, you should:

```
close(launch);
```

(Also, it is traditional to use all-uppercase for file handles.)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues in your approach. First, the sequence "disable button", "doing something non-Tk-ish", "enable button" does not work and the button always stays enabled. The reason is that display changes are only executed if a callback returns or if explicitly `update()` or `idletasks()` is called. To demonstrate this, in the following example the button is never disabled:

```
use Tk;
my $mw = tkinit;
my $b; $b = $mw->Button(-text => 'Click me!', -command => sub {
    $b->configure(-state => 'disabled');
    # $mw->idletasks; # or alternatively: $mw->update;
    sleep 10; # simulate some task
    $b->configure(-state => 'normal');
})->pack;
MainLoop;
```

But if the `idletasks()` or `update()` call is activated, then things work as expected.

The example script has a flaw: while the `sleep()` (or any busy task) is active, no updates to the GUI can be done. The application appears to be frozen to the user. Even window refreshes don't happen anymore. If this is a problem, then the whole script has to be restructured in a non-blocking way. In this case it would be possible to start a new process in the background (as you already do it using the `start` command), but then you have to know when the background process is finished, and enable the button again. One simple approach is to use some kind of "signal file" and check periodically if this signal file was created from the background process. Here's an example which works on Unix systems (but should work on Windows, too, if a custom script is used in the `system()` call):

```
use Tk;
my $mw = tkinit;
my $b; $b = $mw->Button(-text => 'Click me!', -command => sub {
    $b->configure(-state => 'disabled');
    # no idletasks/update necessary now
    system("(rm -f /tmp/signal_file; sleep 10; touch /tmp/signal_file) &");
    my $repeater; $repeater = $mw->repeat(1000, sub {
        if (-e "/tmp/signal_file") {
        unlink "/tmp/signal_file";
        $b->configure(-state => 'normal');
        $repeater->cancel;
    }
    });
})->pack;
MainLoop;
```

This approach is not very elegant, because it requires a periodic check. A more elegant way can be written with the `Tk::IO` module, but it's possible that this is working only on Unix platforms:

```
use Tk;
use Tk::IO;
my $exec_fh;
my $mw = tkinit;
my $b; $b = $mw->Button(-text => 'Click me!', -command => sub {
    $b->configure(-state => 'disabled');
    # no idletasks/update necessary now
    $exec_fh = Tk::IO->new(-linecommand => sub {
    # empty, we're not interested in the output
    }, -childcommand => sub {
        $b->configure(-state => 'normal');
    });
    $exec_fh->exec("sleep 10");
})->pack;
MainLoop;
```

Further good readings are the `Tk::fileevent` Pod and maybe you can give `AnyEvent` a try.